# Snowflake handling of nulls in a join

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is a Snowflake question about nulls and joins. Suppose I have

```
contacts AS (
  SELECT
    c.user_id
    , [... more fields ...] 
  FROM prod_contact AS c
  LEFT (?) JOIN bridge as b
    ON c.user_id = b.user_id
```

The bridge table has about 100,000 entries with a null user_id about 1M other entries with a non-null User_Id.   The prod_contact table has no records with a null user_id.  I want these null User_id records to show up in the contacts table.  I have tried LEFT, RIGHT, FULL OUTER, OUTER RIGHT, basically every type of join and in none of my attempts can I get the bridge table's user_id=null rows into contacts.  Is it impossible due to Snowflake treatments of nulls?   Perhaps I have to transform the null in the bridge table to some other value in a pre-processing step  to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you want to join them to since the keys don't match? If you want all the rows with null `user_id` in the bridge table to appear exactly once with all columns `NULL` from the `PROD_CONTACT` table side of the join, that's just a left join with a union all and a select with a where `b.user_id` is null.

Comment: Remember that NULL means "undefined", and therefore won't match in any join logic (inner, outer or otherwise) on that value unless you use NULL processing logic (such as IS NULL).

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desired results?

Comment: FYI - this is not unique to Snowflake.  Treatment of NULL values is pretty consistent across just about every SQL-based system that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 5):

So there is a point about joins.

The rows of the first table are "matched" to the rows of the second, so a LEFT JOIN keeps all first table rows, even if they don't match thus:

```
with prod_contact(user_id, p_val) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'p_1'),
    (2, 'p_2'),
    (3, 'p_3')
), bridge(user_id, b_val) as (
  select * from values
    (1, 'b_1'),
    (null, 'b_2'),
    (null, 'b_3')
)
SELECT
    c.*,
    b.b_val
FROM prod_contact AS c
LEFT JOIN bridge as b
    ON c.user_id = b.user_id
```

gives:

| USER_ID | P_VAL | B_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p_1 | b_1 |
| 2 | p_2 | null |
| 3 | p_3 | null |

because those null values do not match anything.

If we swap the table order (with the same fake data CTE's)

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    b.b_val
FROM bridge as b
LEFT JOIN prod_contact AS c
    ON c.user_id = b.user_id
```

we get all the bridge rows, but 2 of those don't match a prod_contact, as is expected.

| USER_ID | P_VAL | B_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p_1 | b_1 |
| null | null | b_2 |
| null | null | b_3 |

(which is the exact same results as a RIGHT JOIN which keeps the non-matched second table)

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    b.b_val
FROM prod_contact AS c
RIGHT JOIN bridge as b
    ON c.user_id = b.user_id
```

A full outer keeps the "non-matched" from both sides:

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    b.b_val
FROM bridge as b
FULL OUTER JOIN prod_contact AS c
    ON c.user_id = b.user_id
```

| USER_ID | P_VAL | B_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p_1 | b_1 |
| 2 | p_2 | null |
| 3 | p_3 | null |
| null | null | b_2 |
| null | null | b_3 |

But lastly if you have good id's on both side's but want nulls to actually be paired with a "null row" like if you had a default dimension, and those are the values you wanted to use, there is a function that will match NULL called [EQUAL_NULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/equal_null.html)

```
with prod_contact(user_id, p_val) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'p_1'),
    (2, 'p_2'),
    (3, 'p_3'),
    (null, 'p_default_val')
), bridge(user_id, b_val) as (
  select * from values
    (1, 'b_1'),
    (null, 'b_2'),
    (null, 'b_3')
)
SELECT
    c.*,
    b.b_val
FROM prod_contact AS c
JOIN bridge as b
    ON EQUAL_NULL(c.user_id, b.user_id)
```

| USER_ID | P_VAL | B_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p_1 | b_1 |
| null | p_default_val | b_2 |
| null | p_default_val | b_3 |

Answer (score 0):

Remember that NULL is intended to be "undefined", so there is no join logic that will utilize it in a result set unless you specify NULL processing in your query.

Try the following, essentially what Greg proposed earlier.

```
    create or replace table contacts AS 
    (
    SELECT
        c.user_id,
        [... more fields ...] 
    FROM 
        prod_contact c,
        full outer join bridge b
        on c.user_id = b.user_id
    union all
    select b.user_id, 
    [... more fields, but matching the type and count of columns above]
    from bridge b
        where b.user_id is null
    );
```